# How create typescript interface with unknown and known keys?

Tags: typescript

My typescript type starts with an unknown key, followed by two known keys. I tried to use an index signature for the first key, but that seems to affect all following keys as well.

Desired result:

```
let objOne:MyThing = {"anything":0.534843, label:"hello", confidence:0.94394}
let objTwo:MyThing = {"bleep":0.348989843, label:"heyyy", confidence:0.48394}
```

I tried to write this type as

```
interface MyThing {
    [key: string] : string;
    label : string;
    confidence : number;
}
```

But now `confidence` also needs to be a string for some reason.

How can I have just the first key to be any string, but the other two keys should be named `label` and `confidence` ?

Comment: Typescript will _not_ make this easy for you. If you can change your data structure, you are much better off putting that index signature in its own property `{ a: number, data: { [key: string]: string } }`

Comment: Thanks, I missed that post completely